# DOTNETNUKE development

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, dotnetnuke

I'm developing websites using asp.net. Now, I'm interested in developing a website using dotnetnuke. Big question is:

**When using dotnetnuke do I have to develop model for every little thing that is gonna be part of site content (for instance text form and button , datetimepicker, datagrid showing some data from database)?**

As far as I can see you can add content like text, images and video using control panel of dotnet nuke but what if I want to put Image gallery that is using jquery, or just div element containing few controls.

Ps: when I create new website usign dotnetnuke control panel, where can I find html code of that site (is it possible to edit it in visual studio). I'm able to open whole dotnetnuke website and run it but I can see only Default.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

In short, yes and no.

You can put HTML and jquery code into a variety of the modules that come with DotNetNuke, primarily the HTML module.

You can also "code" things using the Razor Host module if you want to add custom functionality to a page that isn't easily done with HTML or jquery.

The HTML code for a DNN site is stored in a database, depending on the module you use on a page that code could be in any number of database tables.

I would recommend taking a look at some of the "basic" webinars on our training page they will get you a general overview of things, and how you do development within the platform. http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Training.aspx#basicWebinars

Also check out the Wiki for more specific development questions and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have HTML code for every page in DNN. But if you want then you can create skins for pages and add html modules for the content in the respective pages.

You can create image gallery which uses jquery, for that you need to create visualizer for that section of images. You need to use the concept of liquid content, which allows you to use jquery, css and HTML(Visualizer Template) for that section.